# DataTable.Select vs List.FindAll

Tags: c#, performance, list, datatable, lookup

**TL;DR Version**

I have some data from a database either in a `DataTable` or in a `List<MyData>`.

Since i want to follow OO principles i prefer to handle the data in the `List<MyData>` but when it comes to performance i run into some trouble.

With roughly 150k items a `myDataList.FindAll(x=>x.Id == someId)` takes about 15 milliseconds while on the other side a `myDataTable.Select($"ID == {someId}")` completes without `StopWatch` being able to clock one millisecond.

Since i need to perform many thousands of searches on my data 15 milliseconds per search soon adds up.

Is there any other List-Type i can use instead of falling back to the `DataRow[]` that `DataTable.Select()` returns? Or am i missing something else here?

**Detailed Version**

I have an application that reads data from two different tables in a database and needs to compute something on this data.

Following OO principles i got myself two lists of objects: `List<MyClass> myClassList` and `List<MyOtherClass> myOtherClassList`.

Since the fact that there is a relationship between the data in the two tables (via a ID column) i now want to move them into another class that combines them to a businessobject: `List<MyBusinessObject> myBusinessObjectList`.

So what i did was the following:

```
foreach (var id in myIdList)
{
    var myTmpClassList = myClassList.FindAll(x => x.Id == id);
    var myTmpOtherClassList = myOtherClassList.FindAll(x => x.Id == id);

    myBusinessObjectList.Add(new MyBusinessObject(myTmpClassList, myTmpOtherClassList );
}
```

With roughly 35k entries in one and 160k entries in the other table this process takes about 15 milliseconds per iteration and soon adds up.

On the other side

```
var dic1 = new Dictionary<string, DataRow[]>;
var dic2 = new Dictionary<string, DataRow[]>;
foreach (var id in myIdList)
{
    dic1.Add(id, myDataTable.Select($"ID == {id}");
    dic2.Add(id, myOtherDataTable.Select($"ID == {id}");
}
```

completes in no time.

But since i prefer to handle `Objects` over `Dictionary<string, DataRow[]>` i wonder if there is another approach i can take.

Comment: Did you try the same test by property other than ID? Because I suspect the ID is set as UniqueKey in DataTable, thus having an index, and of course binary search is much faster than linear search.

Comment: I did not try this with another property but the `DataTable` has no UniqueKey so i don't expect any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
foreach (var id in myIdList)
{
    var myTmpClassList = myClassList.FindAll(x => x.Id == id);
    var myTmpOtherClassList = myOtherClassList.FindAll(x => x.Id == id);

    myBusinessObjectList.Add(new MyBusinessObject(myTmpClassList, myTmpOtherClassList );
}
```

you perform 2 linear searches **per each** id, leading to `O(K * (N + M))` time complexity (where `K = myIdList.Count`, `N = myClassList.Count`, `M = myOtherClassList.Count`).

You can use LINQ [group joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_1) for correlating data, which use quite efficient hash based implementation, thus leading to a linear time complexity operation:

```
var myBusinessObjectList =
    (from id in myIdList
     join x in myClassList on id equals x.Id into myClassGroup
     join y in myOtherClassList on id equals y.Id into myOtherClassGroup
     select new MyBusinessObject(myClassGroup.ToList(), myOtherClassGroup.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much. I should learn more LINQ!